# FormSheet modal dialog won't hide

Tags: dialog, xamarin.ios, modal-dialog

I have a modal dialog that I show using the following code:

```
private void ShowUpdateDialog(float version, bool breakingChanges, string hint, string storeLink, string changelog, params string[] pars)
    {
        var dialog = new UpdatePopupController(this, new RectangleF(20, 20, 550, 600));
        dialog.WantsFullScreenLayout = true;
        dialog.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FormSheet;
        dialog.ModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.FlipHorizontal;
        dialog.ModalInPopover = true;
        UIDevice.CurrentDevice.BeginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications();
        dialog.ShowData(version, breakingChanges, hint, storeLink, changelog, pars);
        dialog.WillRotate(UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarOrientation, 0);
        NavigationController.PresentModalViewController(dialog, true);
        dialog.BecomeFirstResponder();
    }
```

I get this result (that is what I expected):

[image: Modal dialog showing]

Now I want to implement closing the dialog by taping out of the gray content of the dialog. How can I do it? The dialog itself inherits from UIViewController.

Comment: The solution in the accepted answer doesn't work on iOS 11.2 with Xamarin.Forms 2.5.0, have you that approach recently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont make it Modal. Then it works

```
dialog.ModalInPopover = false;
```

Comment: Finally a nice and simple solution that just works. No need for additional gesture recognizers and such. Cheers mate!

Comment: That doesn't seem to work on iOS 11.2 with Xamarin.Forms 2.5.0

Answer (score 1):

[See this question which asks the same thing.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623417/iphone-sdk-dismissing-modal-viewcontrollers-on-ipad-by-clicking-outside-of-it)

Personally I would have a button which upon TouchDown would dismiss the modal view.

Comment: Sure I can add a button. But I'd prefer to achieve the functionality that you have i.e. under details view of a prodcast in iTunes.