# Xcode: Creating A Popup UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I would like to create a UIVewController and have it popup similar to what is shown in this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzMKk.png

When the user taps outside the popup window, the window (view controller) goes away.
**Can someone please provide some example code as far as what goes in the .h files, and .m file, and any extra steps I may need to follow in the interface builder?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use UIPopoverController - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIPopoverController

Comment: From every tutorial I've viewed regarding the UIPopoverController does not appear to be what is shown in the image I provided. In the image, they do not have an arrow pointing at a certain object, it's just a popup view/viewcontroller. Are you sure this is what they are using as shown in the image?

Comment: Use this to display popover without arrow (arrow direction 0 means no arrow) `[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:anItem permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:YES];`

Answer (score 0):

It's just a UIViewController presented modally with the popup's view controller `modalPresentationStyle` set to `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`.

```
MyPopupViewController *popup = ...
popup.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentModalViewController:popup animated:YES];
```

From the docs regarding `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` presentation style...

> The width and height of the presented view are smaller than those of
>   the screen and the view is centered on the screen. If the device is in
>   a landscape orientation and the keyboard is visible, the position of
>   the view is adjusted upward so that the view remains visible. All
>   uncovered areas are dimmed to prevent the user from interacting with
>   them.

You'll need to detect touches on the darkened area to allow the form to be dismissed that way. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623417/iphone-sdk-dismissing-modal-viewcontrollers-on-ipad-by-clicking-outside-of-it#6180584) has some details on implemented that.