# Close partially shown modal view controller by tapping outside of the view controller

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, transition, modalviewcontroller

I made a custom modal transition by using UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning.  After the transition has completed, a modally shown view controller fills part of parent view that some part of parent view controller is still visible.

I need to know how to **detect tap on outside of shown view controller**(or partially shown parent view controller) so I can use it to close the modal. I understand how to add gesture to a view but I cannot find which view to add a gesture to.

I looked through stackoverflow but there aren't example specifically for custom modal transition.

Here is a code for custom transition

```
class PartialSlideInAnimationController: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    var direction: SlideAnimationDirectionStyle

    var duration: TimeInterval = 0.125
    var presentedControllerWidth: CGFloat      = 250

    let fadeAlpha: CGFloat = 0.5

    init(direction: SlideAnimationDirectionStyle) {
        self.direction = direction
        super.init()
    }

    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return TimeInterval(duration)
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

        // Setup Views
        guard let presentedFromVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from) else {transitionContext.completeTransition(false); return }
        guard let presentingToVC  = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to)   else {transitionContext.completeTransition(false); return }
        let contrainerView = transitionContext.containerView // アニメーションはこのViewで行われる、アニメーションを実装する presenter, presenteeをこの上に載せないとアニメーションが動かない

        // Setup Frames
        let positionHidden = CGRect(x: contrainerView.frame.width + 1, y: 0, width: presentedControllerWidth, height: contrainerView.frame.height)
        let positionShown  = CGRect(x: contrainerView.frame.width - presentedControllerWidth, y: 0, width: presentedControllerWidth, height: contrainerView.frame.height)

        switch direction {

        case .slideIn:

            contrainerView.addSubview(presentingToVC.view)
            presentingToVC.view.frame = positionHidden

            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
                presentingToVC.view.frame = positionShown
                presentedFromVC.view.alpha = self.fadeAlpha

            }, completion: { success in
                transitionContext.completeTransition( success )
            })

        case .slideOut:

            contrainerView.addSubview(presentedFromVC.view)
            presentedFromVC.view.frame = positionShown

            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
                presentedFromVC.view.frame = positionHidden
                presentingToVC.view.alpha = 1.0

            }, completion: { success in
                transitionContext.completeTransition( success )

            })
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using `UIGestureRecognizer` yet? The UIGestureRecognizer can be utilized to recognize tap events, both inside a child view controller and a parent view controller. For swift 3, there should be a `handleTapBehind` function of the `UIRecognizerDelegate` that should allow you to do what you're looking for.

See if the what is documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25638409/dismiss-modal-form-sheet-view-on-outside-tap-ios-8)

See the "Swift 3.1 solution that works in both portrait and landscape" in the linked post.