# How to detect tap/touch outside a UIViewController

Tags: swift, uikit

As below screenshot showed, I have a black dimmer View on the top and a viewController on the bottom(the white one) with half screen size.

What I want to do is when I tap on the dimmer place aka. outside of the viewController. This viewController should be dismissed.

YES, I found tons of topic using `touchesBegan`. But in my case it is not working, the problem is `touchesBegan` cannot detect touches outside current presented viewController. It would never be triggered when I click on that dimmer view.

And if I use Gesture check on the dimmer view, I could not dismiss this viewController from dimmer view too.

Any advice is welcomed if anyone met this similar situation with me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add a `UITapGesture` to the views window, look here: [Dismiss modal view form sheet controller on outside tap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102497/dismiss-modal-view-form-sheet-controller-on-outside-tap)

Comment: Yes, I could add UITapGesture to my dimmer view. And I check this post, it is not clear for me that how could I connect this view to my modalViewController since I need to dismiss it.

Comment: on your modalViewController you could add the gesture using `view.window?.add...` then when the tap Is recognised you can call `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: Thanks. I add gesture `view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDismiss)))` in my modalViewController. The effect is same with implement `touchBegan`,  it only could detect the touches inside this viewController, instead I need to detect touches outside it.

Comment: use view.window? instead of just view - Sorry for the late reply

Comment: NP, I try `view.window?` too, but this time it could trigger the tapGesture, but all space inside or outside viewController would be detected. Because when specify the window, it means the whole screen, if it is worked in your side?