# How to dismiss modal form sheet when clicking outside of view?

Tags: ios, swift

I don't know how exactly to achieve the following in Swift:

I am displaying a modal form sheet popup in my iPad app. In order to dismiss this view I have added a button that dismisses it. But what I really want is for it to dismiss when you click outside of the view. Almost the same behaviour as the popover. I have tried achieving this by adding tap gestures, making it a popover, any of the presentation styles, nothing works.

Has someone maybe done this so that you can point me in the right direction?

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44171475/3397217) shows how to do it these days.

Answer (score 12):

I had to display some screens like a popup in my app, so I've made a
base class that looks like this:

```
class MyBasePopUp: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

var tap: UITapGestureRecognizer!
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    
    tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onTap(sender:)))
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    tap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    tap.delegate = self
    self.view.window?.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

internal func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}

internal func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    let location = touch.location(in: self.view)
    
    if self.view.point(inside: location, with: nil) {
        return false
    }
    else {
        return true
    }
}

@objc private func onTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    
    self.view.window?.removeGestureRecognizer(sender)
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This is just to dismiss the popup, be careful if you have multiple gestures.

Comment: This mostly did what I need.  Maybe I'm using it slightly differently, but I had to use `presentedViewController.view` instead of `self.view` before it would correctly recognize taps, and I had to remove the first line of `onTap` or else it would only work once.

Comment: if the popup is not destroyed,  it will add another gesture rec. when user opens the popup, that's why i needed self.view.window?.removeGestureRecognizer(sender)

Comment: In `let location = touch.location(in: self.view)` I had to change `self.view` to use my particular view, but after that, things worked as intended.