# Dissmiss alertview created by LMAlertView on outside tap

Tags: ios, objective-c

I used LMAlertView to custom the AlertView which shown in GIF [http://imgur.com/a/Bu8PR](https://imgur.com/a/Bu8PR)

**Q: How to dismiss this alertview on outside tap?**

I tried some solution shown in [Dismiss modal view form sheet controller on outside tap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102497/dismiss-modal-view-form-sheet-controller-on-outside-tap).

The AlertView dismissed with [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28897981/7043064) but the view also lost control and get the error message below

```
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <LMEmbeddedViewController: 0x12fd03bf0>.
```

For the above error i tried to set `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` animated form YES to NO or use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{` to contain `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`, but still didn't work.

Solution:

```
[[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
[[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES 
completion:nil];
```