# dismiss modal view by tapping outside

Tags: modalviewcontroller

I'm presenting a view as UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal and want to recognize tapping outside this modal view to dismiss it. An example is the iTunes app on iPad e. g. for viewing songs in the album.

Comment: This has already been asked and answered. Hope this helps, worked for me :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623417/iphone-sdk-dismissing-modal-viewcontrollers-on-ipad-by-clicking-outside-of-it