# Get UIActionSheet to perform action

Tags: iphone, ios, uiactionsheet

This a rookie question.. I created the UIActionSheet. Now how do i get it perform "delete" when its pressed.

```
- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake )
    {
        // Handle shake notification
    UIActionSheet *shakeActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                                  delegate:self
                                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                    destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete"
                                                         otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [shakeActionSheet showInView:self];
    }

    if ([super respondsToSelector:@selector(motionEnded:withEvent:)])
        [super motionEnded:motion withEvent:event];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to call `UIActionSheet` delegate methods

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{

    NSString *title = [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if([title isEqualToString:@"Delete"])
    {
     //do your stuff in here

     }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! ok i also want the action sheet to disappear and do nothing if the user decides to touch the screen instead of the cancel button. how do i implement that?

Comment: you need to use `UITapGestureRecognizer`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623417/iphone-sdk-dismissing-modal-viewcontrollers-on-ipad-by-clicking-outside-of-it

Comment: That's a new question.  You should mark one of these answers correct.  And tap gesture recognizer is also a good answer.

Comment: I didn't know you could do that. how do i "mark one of these answers correct"? @danh

Comment: There's a little checkbox near the votes for the answer.  Simply click it on the answer that helped you the most.

Comment: It's far from ideal to perform actions based on the button title. Using the button index is much safer. Comparing the title will fail if you change the button's title (but forget to update this code) or if your app supports more than one language.

Comment: @SpaceDust i tried your suggestion. However its not working for me. i posted a new question about it and would appreciate your help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657919/get-uiactionsheet-to-dismiss-by-pressing-anywhere-on-screen

Comment: @user1779598 you can try change `if([title isEqualToString:@"Delete"])` to `if(buttonIndex==integer){}` its not big deal.

Answer (score 1):

Your class has to conform to the `UIActionSheetDelegate` protocol.

Then override the `actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:` method, evaluate the clicked button and act accordingly.

See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIModalViewDelegate_Protocol/UIActionSheetDelegate/UIActionSheetDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006799) for more info.

Comment: u mean like this @interface yellowView : UIView <UIActionSheetDelegate> ?

Comment: Yes, correct. By this you tell the framework, that you'll implement one or more delegate methods.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on to other two solutions, you can add the delegate in your `- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` method like this (assuming your class implements `UIActionSheetDelegate` protocol):

```
shakeActionSheet.delegate = self;
```

Comment: doesn't the argument "delegate:self" in the init method handle that?