# Get Bounds after tap outside from a UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller, popover, dismiss

Imagine a ViewController with 2 UITextFields. When you tap on TextField1, it appears a Popover.

Now, if I tap out of the popover, it disappears (OK). However, I want this behaviour:

- If I click outside of the popover, and this tap is on TextField2, I want to dismiss the popover (OK), AND throw an event (for example, open other popover from TextField2).

I've tried this solution: [Iphone SDK dismissing Modal ViewControllers on ipad by clicking outside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623417/iphone-sdk-dismissing-modal-viewcontrollers-on-ipad-by-clicking-outside-of-it)

But handleTapBehind method doesn't execute if popover is visible.

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you should implement `UIPopoverControllerDelegate`

and use

```
popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:
popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:
```

[see More](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for details

Comment: I've already implemented. But with these methods I only receive by parameter the UIPopoverController reference. I need the bounds of the tap to know If user has tapped on another view (for example, a Textfield, button, etc.)