# how make view transition like iPad appstore on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiviewanimationtransition

I want to make a view transition, like iPad AppStore on iOS 7, click a item(app) and popping a detail view with flip vertical, and tapping outside of detail view will dismiss, this view transition is neither like popover and modal transition.
So, how can I make this transition...

Appreciation for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also looking for the transition animation. But I did figure out how to accomplish the tapping outside of window to dismiss/close. It can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623417/iphone-sdk-dismissing-modal-viewcontrollers-on-ipad-by-clicking-outside-of-it).

In your `viewDidAppear` you create a UITapGestureRecognizer and add it to the view's window. Like so:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapBehind:)];
[recognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
recognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
[self.view.window addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

`handleTapBehind` checks to see is the Gesture's state has ended and get's the location of the tap and dismisses the view/window

```
- (void)handleTapBehind:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender{
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        CGPoint location = [sender locationInView:nil]; //Passing nil gives us coordinates in the window

        //Check to see if it's in or outside. If outside, dismiss the view.
        if (![self.view pointInside:[self.view convertPoint:location fromView:self.view.window] withEvent:nil]){
            // Remove the recognizer first so it's view.window is valid.
            [self.view.window removeGestureRecognizer:sender];
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Start [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/transitionWithView%3aduration%3aoptions%3aanimations%3acompletion%3a). This is an example:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:newView
                  duration:1
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft 
                animations:^{         // put the animation block here
                           }
                completion:NULL];
```