# Dismiss PresentedViewController while present from UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller, presentviewcontroller

PresentedViewController present from popoverview, this is the code I'm using

```
SearchPropertyVC *SearchPropertyVC *centerViewController = (SearchPropertyVC *)[board instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vcSearchPropertyID"];
UINavigationController *ConDetVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:centerViewController];
ConDetVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
ConDetVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
ConDetVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

[self presentViewController:ConDetVC animated:YES completion:nil];
ConDetVC.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 700, 670);
```

controller open fine, when I was try to close the controller I'm getting this Warning

**"Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller  while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!"**

after that if I click any button the app will crashed.

this the code I'm using to dismiss the view

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
             [(UINavigationController *)self.presentingViewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
         }];

if (![self.presentedViewController isBeingDismissed])
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

when I try to dismiss the popover view itself getting the same warning

Comment: for popOverView set the property like @property(nonatomic,retain)    UIPopoverController *popOverControlObj;
 I hope it will works.

Comment: You can either unwind or pop with delay.

Comment: before present ConDetVC view have you presented any other view? if yes then you have to dismiss that view first

Comment: remove this line and try it  [(UINavigationController *)self.presentingViewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: I add delay and try to close popoverview but both popover & presentingViewController will be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At very first correct below line.

```
 SearchPropertyVC *SearchPropertyVC *centerViewController = (SearchPropertyVC *)[board instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vcSearchPropertyID"];

 SearchPropertyVC *searchPropertyVC = (SearchPropertyVC *)[board instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vcSearchPropertyID"];
```

choose any one presentation style,

```
 ConDetVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
 ConDetVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
```

either page sheet or form sheet.

And while you try to present, use object of view controller you want to present.

```
 [self presentViewController:ConDetVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And when it being dismissed, just write,

```
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
         // write you code here
     }];
```

Comment: [ConDetVC presentViewController:ConDetVC animated:YES completion:nil]; this will get error... Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modal view controller on itself. Presenting controller is <UINavigationController: 0xc08ccf0>.'

Comment: Actually this is the process I want to do -- 
From viewcontroll -> barbutton click -> popoverview (button click here) -> (need to close popupview) open a model presentviewcontroller (Button click) -> (close presentviewcontroller) opne a new presentviewcontroller. and if I click out side the presentviewcontroller need to close the presentviewcontroller.

Comment: @Rajesh,   I am sorry for my mistake. Please see edited answer.

Comment: I fix everything, now only one problem I have, need to close presentviewcontroller when we click outside the window...

Comment: You can dismiss presented view controller on touches event after finding presented view controller

Comment: I follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623417/iphone-sdk-dismissing-modal-viewcontrollers-on-ipad-by-clicking-outside-of-it its working but inside the controller I have another view it have UITapGestureRecognizer that will not work.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you :

```
 [self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion:^(void) {
             [self presentViewController:myController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
```