# Dismiss PresentationViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3

I have a custom `PresentationViewController` which has a half screen size height and full screen size width.

[image]

I want to press outside `PresentationViewController` to dismiss it.

I tried adding a button in under ViewController, but this button's action never be called.

I also tried adding a button in `PresentationViewController` that have frame equal to `view.frame` and send an action for `touchUpOutside`, this button's action never be called also.

So how to dismiss this `PresentationViewController`

Comment: Use method touch began, if your touchView == self.view then dismiss presented vC

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, thank you, adding tapGesture to `self.view.window` works for me.

Comment: you need the answer in swift or objective C

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Either will do :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In underViewController, I add a gesture like this:

```
self.tapGestureDismissTopFanVC = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(PlayDetailViewController.dismissTopFanVC(_:)))
self.view.window?.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureDismissTopFanVC!) // not self.view.addGesture 
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
```

then this gesture action:

```
func dismissTopFanVC(_ tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if presentedViewController is TopFanPopOverViewController {
        presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: true) {
            self.view.backgroundColor = .clear
            if self.tapGestureDismissTopFanVC != nil {
                self.view.window?.removeGestureRecognizer(self.tapGestureDismissTopFanVC!)
                self.tapGestureDismissTopFanVC = nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add the gesture recognizer to the view's window

**For Swift3**

```
var recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(yourViewController.handleTap(_:)))
recognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
recognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
self.view.window?.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
```

and call the function as like

```
 func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
if sender.state == .ended {
    var location: CGPoint = sender.location(in: nil)
    if !self.view.point(inside: self.view.convertPoint(location, from: self.view.window), withEvent: nil) {
        self.view.window?.removeGestureRecognizer(sender)
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
}
```

for **objective C** you can take the reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623417/iphone-sdk-dismissing-modal-viewcontrollers-on-ipad-by-clicking-outside-of-it)